# ContentControl Visibility over DataTemplate and DataContext property

Tags: wpf, xaml, visibility, datatemplate, contentcontrol

Is there a posibility to change the visibility of the `ContentControl` over the `DataTemplate` of the content? I have the following situation:

- A custom control (button with four states - background image for each).
- A view model to use this control as property in other controls.
- Style with corresponding DataTemplate

  ```
  <!-- Default Style for Image Button -->
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type cont:StateImageButton}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ImageButtonTemplate}" />
  </Style>

  <!-- Default Representation of ImageButtonViewModel -->
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StateImageButtonViewModel}">
        <cont:StateImageButton DefaultImage="{Binding DefaultImageName}"
                                         FocusedImage="{Binding FocusedImageName}"
                                         DisabledImage="{Binding DisabledImageName}"
                                         Command="{Binding Command}"
                                         ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                                         IsCancel="{Binding IsCancel}"
                                         IsDefault="{Binding IsDefault}"
                                         Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- The use of content control to show the control in the application

  ```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding CancelButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding ProtocolButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
  </StackPanel>
  ```

If the viewmodel property `IsVisible` of the second control set to false the control is invisible, but not collapsed. So I have a gap between the right border and first control.

If I want to collapse the second `ContentControl` I have to bind the `ContentControl` explicit on the `IsVisible` Property of the binded data.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CancelButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ProtocolButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5"
                    Visibility="{Binding ProtocolButton.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a posibility to avoid this?

**Edit 1:** Test with direct use of control and `DataContext`

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <con:StateImageButton DataContext="{Binding CancelButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
    <con:StateImageButton DataContext="{Binding ProtocolButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
    <!--
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CancelButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ProtocolButton}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />-->
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: *Is there a posibility to avoid this?*... you cannot set the `Visibility` property of a parent control by setting the `Visibility` property of a child control. You *could* avoid it by simply using `Button`s with default `Style`s instead of your custom control, but I guess that you won't want to do that.

Comment: @Sheridan: As I understand WPF is the `ContentControl` a placeholder for content (whatever this is) that is assigned over the `Control` property. I hope there is a solution to collapse the placeholder if the content is collaped too without binding the visibility on each `ContentControl` manuelly.

Comment: Unfortunately, your understanding of the `ContentControl` is flawed. It is *not* just a placeholder for content and if you use the WPF Tree Visualizer in Visual Studio while debugging, you can actually see `ContentControl`s as normal UI elements in the visual tree. You could set your control view model to its `DataContext` internally and then just use your controls normally in XAML (without the `ContentControl`).

Comment: @Sheridan What du you mean with "You could set your control view model to its DataContext internally and then just use your controls normally in XAML"? If I use the control direct without `DataTemplate` I lose the posibility to bind all needed properties once and have to do this on each place I use the control. Or is the a possibility to show the data definied over `DataTemplate` direct without using `ContentControl`?

Comment: I didn't mention your `DataTemplate` at any point. I meant that you could just declare your controls in the view using `<cont:StateImageButton ... />` instead of using a `ContentControl`.

Comment: @Sheridan: If I use the controls in direct way, I have to set all bindings manually. The existing `DataTemplate` does not effect (see Edit 1). The control is faceles without bindings (and functionles). My Facit is that I should bind the visibility of `ContentControl` on the ViewModel to avoid to do a lot more bindings on the pure control.